# Internal and External Fragmentation

Tags: operating-systems

I am working over a homework problem and am confused on how to determine whether there is internal and external fragmentation given the following table:

```
Characteristic                   Design 1 Design 2 Design 3
Physical Memory Address Width:     8 bit    16 bit   32 bit
Virtual (Logical) Address Width:   12 bit   20 bit   24 bit
Page/Frame size in bytes:          16 bytes 32 bytes 64 bytes
```

More specifically, which design has the most internal fragmentation and external fragmentation and why?

Comment: You'll need to give more context here.  What kind of memory management system is this?  What are your definitions of internal and external fragmentation?  The traditional definition of external fragmentation doesn't make any sense in the context of a virtual memory system, for example.  What have you tried and what are you confused about?  (We're not just going to answer your homework question for you.)

Comment: @WanderingLogic I am **guessing** that external fragmentation is referring to the virtual address space and that actual problem size corresponds to MAX(physical address size, virtual address size) (max. utilization of fully populated system memory without paging out to storage or using remapping tricks). With a larger VA than PA, such "fragmentation" would be smaller since a smaller portion of the VA is actively used at any given time. (IMO, this is just another poorly conceived/expressed homework question.)

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)#External_fragmentation) currently defines _external fragmentation_.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. External fragmentation happens over time when small spaces in memory are not effectively employed. This leads to hole everywhere in memory. Therefore it cannot be determined from the chart that there is external fragmentation.

On the other hand, internal fragmentation is the idea when there is over-allocation of memory space to a process. In the above chart, internal fragmentation depends on the page/frame size. Since it is possible for a page to only have one byte of data then larger page sizes have more internal fragmentation. Design 3 has the most spread which is the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I know that external fragmentation occurs by memory problem, when we have less memory space in `mvt` partition (multiprogramming with variable no. of task) called external frag..

when we have less memory space in `mft` partition (multiprogramming with fixed no. of tasks) called internal frag....

Answer (score -1):

External
Fragmentation
happens when a
dynamic
memory
allocation
algorithm
allocates some
memory and a
small piece is
left over that
cannot be
effectively used.
If too much
external
fragmentation
occurs, the amount of usable memory is
drastically reduced. Total memory space
exists to satisfy a request, but it is not
contiguous.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange! What you've written is correct but it doesn't answer the question. The question asks whether internal and/or external fragmentation exists in a specific given situation. You have defined external fragmentation but you haven't addressed the actual question at all.